# Want to migrate query from oracle to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, oracle, recursive-query

Query:

```
Select n 
  from tab1
 where id in (select id 
                from tab2
               start with id=5
             connect by prior parentid=tab2.id) 
   and n like ‘N_%’
```

I tried the below query but its not giving me the correct output. So i need help here

```
With recursive a as (
Select n from tab1 where n like ‘N_%’
Union all
Select id from tab2 join tab2.id=tab1.id)
Select * from a;
```

Query is working but output defers with oracle

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: What about the [many other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]++connect+by) about converting Oracle's connect by to a recursive query in Postgres?

Comment: `START WITH 5` is not valid in Oracle.

Comment: Corrected id =5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recurse first and then filter on the result (rather than trying to join and filter simultaneously):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE a AS (
  SELECT id, parentid
  FROM   tab2
  WHERE  id = 5 -- START WITH clause
UNION ALL
  SELECT tab2.id, tab2.parentid
  FROM   tab2
         INNER JOIN a
         ON a.parentid = tab2.id -- CONNECT BY clause
)
SELECT n
FROM   tab1
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id FROM a)
AND    n LIKE 'N_%';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (n VARCHAR(20), id INT);
CREATE TABLE tab2 (id INT, parentid INT);

INSERT INTO tab1 (n, id)
  SELECT 'NX01', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'XX02', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NY03', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NX04', 4;

INSERT INTO tab2 (id, parentid)
  SELECT 5, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, NULL;
```

Outputs:

| n |
| --- |
| NX01 |
| NX04 |

[PostgreSQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-aI6OsQ5) [Oracle fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rggrXMJs)

Comment: Thanks for the effort but same issue output mismatched

Comment: @user151210 I have updated the answer with a [MRE] and links to fiddles which shows it working. Just saying "output mismatched" is not a constructive statement as it does not tell us what your input is or what your expected output is or where the "mismatch" has occurred; if you want more constructive help then **YOU** need to help yourself and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75787862/edit) to provide a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data and the expected output for that sample data.